# Any software to automatically connect and disconnect from the internet for testing?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, internet-connection

I am checking something out in my connection and I just wanted to ask, is there a way to auto-disconnect and connect the internet.

For example say I want to disconnect the internet in 1.05 minutes and connect after 10, and repeat this action, is there any program that does that on Windows XP and Windows 7?

Comment: Can you just unplug your network cable manually?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it would be to create two batch scripts, one to disable your network adapter, and another to re-enable it, with something like to following:

Disable:

```
netsh interface set interface name="Local Area Connection" admin=disabled
```

Enable:

```
netsh interface set interface name="Local Area Connection" admin=enabled
```

Change the "Local Area Connection" to the name of your NIC.

You can schedule them in Task Scheduler to run whenever you need.

Comment: Of course this disables your entire network, not just your internet connection...